# Parsing Wikipedia API in Android

Tags: java, android

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"21721040":{"pageid":21721040,"ns":0,"title":"Stack Overflow","extract":"Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier question and answer sites such as Experts-Exchange. The name for the website was chosen by voting in April 2008 by readers of Coding Horror, Atwood's popular programming blog.\nIt features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming.\nThe website serves as a platform for users to ask and answer questions, and, through membership and active participation, to vote questions and answers up or down and edit questions and answers in a fashion similar to a wiki or Digg. Users of Stack Overflow can earn reputation points and \"badges\"; for example, a person is awarded 10 reputation points for receiving an \"up\" vote on an answer given to a question, and can receive badges for their valued contributions, which represents a kind of gamification of the traditional Q&A site or forum. All user-generated content is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribute-ShareAlike license.\nClosing questions is a main differentiation from Yahoo! Answers and a way to prevent low quality questions. The mechanism was overhauled in 2013; questions edited after being put \"on hold\" now appear in a review queue. Jeff Atwood stated in 2010 that duplicate questions are not seen as a problem but rather they constitute an advantage if such additional questions drive extra traffic to the site by multiplying relevant keyword hits in search engines.\nAs of April 2014 Stack Overflow has over 4,000,000 registered users, and it exceeded 10,000,000 questions in late August 2015. Based on the type of tags assigned to questions, the top eight most discussed topics on the site are: Java, JavaScript, C#, PHP, Android, jQuery, Python and HTML.\nStack Overflow also has a Jobs section to assist developers in finding their next opportunity. For employers, Stack Overflow provides tools to brand their business, advertise their openings on the site, and source candidates from Stack Overflow's database of developers who are open to being contacted.\n\n"}}}}
```

How to parse this Wikipedia API in Android?

Comment: It looks like JSON, so use a JSON parser.

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: Used Gson if you have json similar pojo with you

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
    try {
        JSONObject objResult = new JSONObject(response);
        String batchComplete = objResult.getString("batchcomplete");

        JSONObject objQuery=objResult.getJSONObject("query");
        JSONObject objPages=objQuery.getJSONObject("pages");
        JSONObject objPagesNo=objPages.getJSONObject("21721040");
        String page_id = objPagesNo.getString("pageid");
        int ns = objPagesNo.getInt("ns");
        String title = objPagesNo.getString("title");
        String extract = objPagesNo.getString("extract");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

OR

If 21721040 is not fixed then 1st fetch key and then value for that key

```
  try {
        JSONObject objResult = new JSONObject(response);
        String batchComplete = objResult.getString("batchcomplete");

        JSONObject objQuery=objResult.getJSONObject("query");
        JSONObject objPages=objQuery.getJSONObject("pages");
        Iterator<String> keys = objPages.keys();
        String key=null;
        if( keys.hasNext() ){
             key = (String)keys.next(); // First key in your json object
        }
        if(key!=null) {
            JSONObject objPagesNo = objPages.getJSONObject(key);
            String page_id = objPagesNo.getString("pageid");
            int ns = objPagesNo.getInt("ns");
            String title = objPagesNo.getString("title");
            String extract = objPagesNo.getString("extract");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: does that "21721040" remains same?

Comment: Check updated ,If 21721040 is not fixed then 1st fetch key and then value for that key